# Angular material2 Moment.js formatting

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs, angular-material2

I want to display the year, month, day, hours, minutes and seconds in the input part of my material datepicker. 
I've successfully overriden the `parse()` and `format()` methods in my custom `DateAdapter` using native Javascript objects. 
 
However, now I want to use Moment.js. I've set up `MomentDateAdapter` and `MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS` as in the offical tutorial.

 
How can I change the **formatting** of my dates? Do I have to override the `format()` and `parse()` methods again, extending `MomentDateAdapter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the module where you import `MomentDateAdapter`, you can configure the formats the following way:

```
import {
  MAT_DATE_FORMATS,
  DateAdapter,
  MAT_DATE_LOCALE
} from '@angular/material';

// See the Moment.js docs for the meaning of these formats:
// https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'L'
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'L',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY'
  }
};

//...
providers: [
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS }
]
```

Comment: Since I asked this question, I figured out the same, but thanks @Rui Marques for adding your answer to my post, so now it's complete!

Comment: No problem. In those cases you are supposed to answer your own question and mark it as accepted so it doesn't remain unanswered :)